# Kafka File Streaming with CSV file located on remote machine?

Tags: apache-kafka, live-streaming

I am using kafka_2.12-2.3.0.
I hava kafka installed on my CentOS Linux Machine lets suppose IP (a.a.a.a). I want to run kafka FileStreamSource from(a.a.a.a)  to CSV file placed on remote machine lets suppose IP(b.b.b.b).

my code of connect-file-source.properties is

```
name=shopfile
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=//xxxxxx/xxx/ABC.csv   
topic=shop_topic
```

After running

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

I am getting Error

```
[2019-09-19 21:34:30,790] WARN Couldn't find file //xxxxxx/xxx/ABC.csv  for FileStreamSourceTask, sleeping to wait for it to be created (org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceTask:109)
[2019-09-19 21:34:31,790] WARN Couldn't find file //xxxxxx/xxx/ABC.csv  for FileStreamSourceTask, sleeping to wait for it to be created (org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceTask:109)
[2019-09-19 21:34:32,791] WARN Couldn't find file //xxxxxx/xxx/ABC.csv for FileStreamSourceTask, sleeping to wait for it to be created (org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceTask:109)
```

However, this code runs fine on my Windows Machine.
Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the FileStreamSource.

You could try installing the FTP source connector and having an FTP server exposing your file. https://github.com/Eneco/kafka-connect-ftp